# Build iOS app using Terminal

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Is there a way to create a iOS without the Xcode IDE, and instead using Terminal and a Text Editor (like Atom)?

With Linux, i can accomplish this to build an Android app using Maven to create the minimum directory structure, compile the files after add them (in the Atom editor), create the APK and upload the package to the device.

Is there any command-line utility to accomplish some of this tasks in MacOSX?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You install XCode or the XCodeBuild tools then you execute xcbuild via terminal to build the iOS app. However, I don't know any utility that builds the xproj for you (which is a bunch of settings and configurations). I don't see the benefit at all. Just install Xcode and build via terminal if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xcodebuild command line tool to build, but there is no apple-provided tool to generate the project files other than Xcode.  Google does have a tool called [gyp](https://gyp.gsrc.io/) which can generate the project files, though I'm not certain your use case is what it was designed for.

Other than that you pretty much have to hold your nose and use Xcode to setup your project, add files, change build settings, etc, and use whatever editor you want to actually edit the code.